# Rewrite rule for clean URLs using .htaccess isn't working for ID after "latestnews"

Tags: htaccess, clean-urls

I am trying to implement clean URLs using *.htaccess*.

Basically after searching for some time I found out this code

```
RewriteRule latestnews/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ http://thinkmovie.in/index.php/latestnews/?nid=$1 [L]
RewriteRule latestnews/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ http://thinkmovie.in/index.php/latestnews/?nid=$1 [L]
```

so when I try to access the following URL

```
http://thinkmovie.in/index.php/latestnews/272
```

it redirects to

```
http://thinkmovie.in/index.php/latestnews?nid=272
```

But what I want is to retain the URL in the browsers address bar as

```
http://thinkmovie.in/index.php/latestnews/272
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your URLs don't really make sense to me, but here is some code that I think looks like what you want to do.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^latestnews/([^/]+) /index.php?nid=$1
```

Comment: I tried this, but the result is the same, When I enter http://thinkmovie.in/index.php/latestnews/272, The url in the browser has to remain the same, but the content should be from, http://thinkmovie.in/index.php/latestnews?nid=272

Comment: Sorry i had to disable joomla's "use clean urls" for this to be working. Its working just fine. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Have you actually tested this? It should work how you want it to - your server shouldn't be returning a 301 or 302 to redirect the user to the new URL. I have the following .htaccess for a cakePHP application and it appends everything after the domain to 'index.php?url=' if the requested file doesn't exist.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```