# What is the htaccess code for a clean URL for a user profile page?

Tags: htaccess, url, clean-urls

I have tried code given on under topic [clean URLs using .htaccess](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15639/clean-urls-using-htaccess), but it is nor working on my website.

Actually I am getting static content, but not getting parameters (dynamic content.) My .htaccess code is

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^user/([^/]+) /user.php?u=$1
```

My PHP file (*user.php*) is:

```
<?php 
echo "ABC";
echo $_GET['u'];

?>
```

My URL is:

```
example.com/simran/user/jack
```

(getting static contents , but not parameters)

Comment: Your URL has the "simran" directory in it but the rewrite rule does not.  Have you tried putting that into your rewrite rule?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to Change:

```
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]+) /user.php?u=$1
```

to:

```
RewriteRule ^simran/user/([^/]+) /user.php?u=$1 [L]
```

or for more flexibility you can use:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/user/([^/]+) /user.php?u=$2 [L]
```

That should make these URL's work

```
example.com/any1user/user/jack
example.com/simran/user/jack
example.com/user/jack
```

I changed $1 to $2 because $1 now points to contents before /user and you're interested in contents after /user. The .* means anything including nothing and punctuation.

In all cases, I always recommend suffixing a rule with an L in square brackets because it means don't process any further rules in the list after the rule is processed.